# Where to find custom themes for office 365 Team sites?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, office-365

where we can find free custom themes for  office 365 team sites.i already checked the pre installed looks in design manager.I need a better theme to look the office 365 as corporate site.please help me to find the Custom free themes.Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can find it [here](http://www.topsharepoint.com/themes) It includes premium themes as well as free themes. Hope it might help you. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I have tried that but i can't find Page layout in editing the page of office 365 site, i have already activated publishing features as well. any idea?.FYI my site collection is team site not a publishing site.

Comment: Are you trying to edit an existing page Or Adding a new page with custom page layout ?

Comment: trying to edit the existing home.aspx page

Comment: See my related answer here: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/247227/background-images-in-sharepoint-online

Answer (score 0):

here are some articles if you are looking to create your own themes in SPOnline

- [Create A Custom Master Page In HTML For SharePoint Online](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/create-a-custom-master-page-in-html-for-sharepoint-online/)
- [Create A Custom Page Layout For SharePoint Online](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/create-a-custom-page-layout-for-sharepoint-online/)